# How to copy connected mdf database file (SQL Server Express)

Tags: backup, sql-server-express, disconnect

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Dataset tables (drag and drop tables from database into dataset window) all connected to my c# application via table adapter components from toolbox that means I have no SQL connection codes into my form and I do not attached anything into SQL by code.

When I try to create a copy from `.mdf` file I get an error

> The process cannot access the file 'c:\DB.mdf' because it is being used by another process.

I tried binary reader copy commands but non of them worked however I can close my app, rerun and make my copy successfully unless I don't run any form that include a online datagridview.

Is there any way to disconnect connection like this from app to do the backup operation?

Answer (score 0):

```
sqllocaldb.exe stop v11.0
sqllocaldb.exe delete v11.0
```